# How to center a logo in nav bar

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time centering a logo on the nav bar for a website I'm working on. I've tried a few things but nothing has been successful. I want to have the logo in the center of the nav bar and the other items on the left and right of it. Currently, everything is spaced out evenly, including the logo, so it is not centered. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
 <nav class="main-nav-outer" id="test">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SeasonalSpecials">Seasonal Specials</a></li>
                <li class="small-logo">
                    <a href="#header"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#Products">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contactbanner">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="res-nav_click" href="#"><i class="fa-bars"></i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
    .main-nav-outer{
    padding:0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;
    box-shadow:0 4px 5px -3px #ececec;
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
}
.main-nav{
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px 0 0px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.main-nav li{
    display:inline;
    margin:0 1px;
}
.main-nav li a{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#222222;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:20px;
    margin:17px 32px;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.main-nav li a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #ec5020;
}

.small-logo{
    padding:0 32px;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-section{
    padding:20px 0 110px;
}
```

Comment: edited the CSS and bootply on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may wanna use bootstrap and try something like this

```
<nav class="main-nav-outer" id="test">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#SeasonalSpecials">Seasonal Specials</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <li class="small-logo">
                            <a href="#header"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <li><a href="#Products">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contactbanner">Contact</a></li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
            <a class="res-nav_click" href="#"><i class="fa-bars"></i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

just change this selector in CSS with the below code

```
.main-nav li a {
            display: inline-block;
            color: #222222;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            text-decoration: none;
            line-height: 20px;
            margin: 17px 10px;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }
```

Comment: I just plugged this into [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new) along with the OP CSS, and your suggested answer puts his `Seasonal Specials` onto a new line

Comment: try the eidted code..i have edited the margin in .main-nav li a

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this and although all the items such as Products and Contact were centered, the logo was still off centered.

Comment: @DhavalChheda haha pretty funny stuff

Comment: @DhavalChheda this is what it looks like with the updated code (black box being the logo in this case) http://s32.postimg.org/8549ct5ad/navbar.png.

Comment: nice..maybe the logo could be a little more inline ( lifting it up a bit )..but this is my opinion and you should stick to your design guide

Comment: @DhavalChheda yeah, that's what I mean. I'm trying to make it more centered but it wont center, even with your code.

Comment: put position:relative on the logo and try to push it up

Comment: @DhavalChheda Just fixed it. I got rid of "<li class="small-logo">" in the html file and it centered. Thank you.

Comment: good job..try to do the CSS as much as possible in the browser ( chrome i like the most ) and then once you are happy with what you have then copy paste it in your CSS before refreshing chrome

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<nav class="main-nav-outer" id="test">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SeasonalSpecials">Seasonal Specials</a></li>
            <li class="small-logo">
                <a href="#header"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#Products">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contactbanner">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a class="res-nav_click" href="#"><i class="fa-bars"></i></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.main-nav-outer{
    padding:0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;
    box-shadow:0 4px 5px -3px #ececec;
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
}
.main-nav{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    list-style:none;
}
.main-nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.main-nav li a{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#222222;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:20px;
    margin:17px 32px;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.main-nav li a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #ec5020;
}

.small-logo{
    padding:0 32px;
}

.main-section{
    padding:20px 0 110px;
}
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/6Lnt3bCcCc)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 378px;
}
.navbar-brand span {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color:green;
} 
.navbar-nav li a{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#222222;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:20px;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom ">
   <div class="container" >
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#"><span class="navbar-logo">STACK OVERFLOW</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">Menu Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Menu Item 2</a></li>
   
    </ul>
    <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs text-center" href="#"><span class="navbar-logo">STACK OVERFLOW</span></a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">Menu Item 1</a></li>
   
    </ul>
  </div>
   </div>
 </nav>
```

When you click on Expand snippet you will see the result..